# C++ - Delete std::string*; heap corruption

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I'm relatively new to C++ memory management, and I'm getting this weird error of heap corruption (plus an automatic breakpoint in Visual Studio before it). Here is the offending code:

```
z_world::z_world(char* name)
{
    unsigned int i, skip;
    char tmp;

    //Load data from file
    std::string* data = loadString(name);

    //Base case if there is no world data
    tiles = NULL;

    w = 0;
    h = 0;

    if(data->length() > 0) {
        //Set up the 'tiles' array
        for(i = 0; i < data->length(); i++) {
            if(data->at(i) == '\n')
                h++;
            if(h == 0)
                w++;
        }
        tiles = new int[data->length()-h];

        //Load Data
        skip = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < data->length(); i++) {
            if(data->at(i) == '\n') {
                skip++;
                printf("\n");
                continue;
            }
            tmp = data->at(i);
            tiles[i+skip] = atoi(&tmp);
            printf("%i ",tiles[i+skip]);
        }
    }
    delete data;
}
```

Here's where I load in the string:

```
std::string* loadString(char* name)
{
    ifstream in(name);
    std::string* input = new string();

    while(in) {
        std::string line;
        getline(in,line);
        input->append(line);
        input->append("\n");
    }

    in.close();

    return input;
}
```

I get the breakpoint and error inside of "delete data;", which makes me think that "data" gets deleted somewhere before that, but I can't find where it would. For reference, this method is to create an object that contains world data for a game in the form of a virtual 2D integer array (for the ID's of the tiles).

Comment: You would be better off just returning a string by value and forgetting all about memory management.

Comment: Are you sure it is `tiles[i+skip]` instead of `tiles[i-skip]`?

Comment: data does not get deleted anywhere else - it might get corrupted though, because you are writing out of bounds of the tiles array for instance. 2 fixes: 1) do not use raw pointers, but smart pointers or pass std::string by value 2) use std::vector< int > instead of raw array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Youre problem is probably here:

```
tiles[i+skip] = atoi(&tmp);
```

Problem 1:
It should be `-skip`

```
tiles[i - skip] =
```

Problem 2:
The `atoi()` command is being used incorrectly (tmp does not contain a string). But also I don't think `atoi()` is the appropriate method. I think what you are looking for is simple assignment. The conversion from char to int is automatic:

```
 tiles[i - skip] = tmp;
```

Problem 3:
You are not using objects correctly. In this situation there is no need to generate dynamic objects and create a mess with dynamic memory management. It would be simpler to just to create automatic objects and pass those back normally:

```
std::string* loadString(char* name)
      //   ^  Don't do this.



std::string loadString(std::string const& name)
//  ^^^^^^^  return a string by value.
//           The compiler will handle memory management very well.
```

In general you should not be passing pointers around. In the few situations where you do need pointers they should be held within a smart pointer object or containers (for multiple objects) so that their lifespan is correctly controlled.

Comment: This worked, thanks! The heap corruption error was caused by problem 1, but I also fixed the other problems based on your and others' suggestions.

Comment: You should also look at: `tiles = new int[data->length()-h];` another un-needed use of new. Prefer to use `std::vector<int>` as a container of sub objects.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi(&tmp);`
atoi expects a pointer to a null terminated string - not a pointer to a char

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to dynamically allocate the string in the code you've shown. Change the `loadString` function to

```
std::string loadString(char* name)
{
    ifstream in(name);
    std::string input;

    // ...

    return input;
}
```

In the caller

```
std::string data = loadString( name );
```

Now there's no need to `delete` the string after you're done.

Instead of

```
int *tiles = NULL;
tiles = new int[data->length()-h];
```

use

```
std::vector<int> tiles;
tiles.resize(data.length() - h);
```

Also, if you do need to dynamically allocate objects you should be using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's really the problem. He allocates with new, and deletes once afterwards, whatever the problem is, it will probably manifest itself on the stack as well.

Comment: @enobayram It's not the cause of the heap corruption he's seeing, that probably has to do with overwriting the bounds of the `tiles` array as stated by @stijn in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in

```
tiles[i+skip] = atoi(&tmp);
```

For example, for a string

```
Hello\n
World\n
```

and for the loop iteration at the point of `i == 10`, `skip` is already 1 (since we have encountered the first `\n` before) and you are writing to `tiles[10 + 1]`, but `tiles` only has been allocated as an array with 10 elements.

Answer (score 0):

May be the variable input is local to this function. So after returning from this the memory is freed. So, calling later delete on this string tries to free already freed memory.